# Why my checkBox statement doesnt works?

Tags: asp.net, web

Why my checkBox statements doesnt works?I've used session as you seen(because my homework so dissmiss if it usefull or not):

```
<form id="ShoppingCart" action="Final.aspx">
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="CallOfDutyCheckBox" />
  <%


         if (CallOfDutyCheckBox.Checked)
             Session["Username_CallOfDutyCheckBox_price"] = "5";
          %>
    <input type="submit" value="Buy It"    />

   </form>




<form id="Final">
    <div>
        <%


            Response.Write(Session["Username_CallOfDutyCheckBox_price"]);
             %>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: To make it work first add `runat="server"` to the form and get rid of the second form.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand when you click the checkbox, the code at the server does not run yet?   Click submit to submit the form with the value of the checkbox.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint on the server side code, does it trip?

Comment: Did you look at the value of CallOfDutyCheckBox and the value of  Session["Username_CallOfDutyCheckBox_price"]?

Comment: Yes the main idea of this to check in the first page,which checkBox was checked and in the final form you'll see a string of numbers,which connected to checkBox that were checked...All this by using only Session

Comment: And when you looked at the value of CallOfDutyCheckBox and the value of Session["Username_CallOfDutyCheckBox_price"] as you stepped through the code, what part isn't working?